# What is difference of Class Library(.net core) and Class Library(.Net Standard)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am working for Azure Data Factory v1 custom activity.
I now know Class library(in dll) needs to be put inside Blob Container.
However, i have two option for Class Library in VS2017 below.

- Class Library(.net core)
- Class Library(standard.net)

Which one should I choose?
Also, what are the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Class Library(.net core)**

.Net Core class library give you a ability to develop class for .Net Core Framework project. You can not use this class for .NetFramework project. Because they support different libraries and environments.

**Class Library(standard.net)**

When .Net Core Framework published, a new requirement was born. Some developer want to use some classes both of framework (.Net Core Framework and .Net Framework). For this reason a new structure was developed that we call us .Net Standard 2.0. When you develop a class in .Net Standard, you can use it for both framework. This class is guaranteed that support all of two framework. In this case, you can not use some of library with .Net Standard class. Because some of library support only one framework between .Net Core and .Net Framework.

**Class Library(.Net Framework)**

This class support only from .Net Framework

**Which Library To Use?**

You can chose these one of them according to your requirements.

Comment: Hi, Eyup!
Thank you for detailed information between different standard. 
I've been using them but never figured out difference.
Now, I can research further detail of them with your knowledge.

Great thank you.

Comment: I am very happy if you hep you :D Please set as green click if you solve your problem...